# Python not extracting correct data from Excel sheets using CSV indices

Tags: python, excel, csv

I am writing Python code that collects selected product data from multiple Excel sheets into a single Excel sheet. Since the columns containing the data I want to extract are located in different places in each Excel sheet, I have collected the indices of the columns containing the product codes, prices, and stock information in a CSV file named list.csv. In my code, I am iterating over the rows of the CSV using a for loop, and within that, I am populating my table with data from one of the external sheets using another for loop. So far, I have written the code such that the "stock" variable is set equal to the data in the column specified by the index indicated in the given row of the CSV file. This is what it looks like in practice:

`stock = j[i[6]]`

However, the variable is returning the data in the seventh column of the "i" table for the given row instead of the column specified by the index in the CSV. What could be the problem, and how can I solve it?

Thank you in advance for your help!

Comment: is `i` 0 based by chance?

Comment: Yes, i is based on zero.

Comment: "stock information in a CSV file named list.csv." <--- do you have a test csv that u can use to actually test if the csv file read is successful.?

Comment: I tested the CSV file, and it works, yes.